# Reference request: Oldest dimensional analysis books with exercises?

Tags: resource-recommendations, dimensional-analysis, history

Per the title, what are some of the oldest dimensional analysis books out there with unsolved exercises? Maybe there are some hidden gems from a long time ago out there.

Comment: They won’t be prior to the lives of Rayleigh or Buckingham...

Comment: old because you feel you have done most recent ones?

Comment: @SolarMike What did Rayleigh write on dimensional analysis?

Comment: @Geremia we were taught two methods: Rayleigh & Buckingham, I assume that both are still current or do you know better?

Comment: @SolarMike What are the "two methods" of Rayleigh & Buckingham?

Comment: @Geremia perhaps worth some research effort on your part...

Comment: @Geremia have a look : https://fluidfreak.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/rayleigh-method-pi-theorem/ you might find it enlightening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- E. Buckingham, “[On Physically Similar Systems: Illustrations of the Use of Dimensional Equations](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/X5WTJSSZ/Buckingham%20-%201914%20-%20On%20Physically%20Similar%20Systems;%20Illustrations%20of%20th.pdf),” *Physical Review* 4, no. 4 (1914): 345–76.

  - author of the "Buckingham π theorem"
  - discusses the most general form of a physics equation
- Bridgman's [*Dimensional Analysis*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=6104) (1<sup>st</sup> ed. 1922; 2<sup>nd</sup> ed. 1931)

  - problems/exercises on pp. 107-9